# count number of sequences in many fastq files recursively

Tags: bash

I have many fastq files ending with fastq.gz.

```
rep1.fastq.gz
rep2.fastq.gz
rep3.fastq.gz
rep4.fastq.gz
.....
```

I expect my output as

```
rep1.fastq.gz 23516782
rep2.fastq.gz 45126780
rep3.fastq.gz 67543908
rep4.fastq.gz 76425368
```

Where row 1 show each of my input file and row 2 show the count of number of sequences in each file.

To achieve this I wrote a small bash script to count the number of sequences in each file with the number written after each file as an output

```
for sample in *.fastq.gz;do echo -en $sample "\t";(zcat $sample|wc -l)/4|bc ;done
```

I am getting an error:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/4'

Comment: Your error is because you are using a `bc` command out of `bc`: the shell has no idea that `/4` is supposed to be "divide a number by 4". But are you _sure_ this is what you want? There is no guarantee that fastq files will only have 4 lines per sequence. If you know your data well you can use this approach, but if you need to deal with arbitrary fastq files, you cannot assume only 4 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring all that can be wrong in the assumption of 4 lines per sequence... the command that you've shown above should work with the following format

```
for file in *.fastq.gz; do echo -en $file "\t";echo "$(zcat $file| wc -l)"/4 |bc;done
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running this:

```
(zcat $sample|wc -l)/4|bc
```

The lone `/4` there isn't understood by the shell, and this is why it fails. I suspect what you want is to get the *result* of the command `zcat $sample|wc -l` and then print that value along with `/4` and pass that to `bc`. If so, you need `$()` and not just `()` and you also need to quote it:

```
echo "$(zcat $sample|wc -l)/4" | bc
```

So this would mean:

```
for sample in *.fastq.gz; do 
    echo -en $sample "\t"; echo "$(zcat $sample|wc -l)/4" | bc 
done
```

Or, a bit more portably:

```
for sample in *.fastq.gz; do 
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$sample" "$(echo "$(zcat "$sample" | wc -l)/4" | bc )"
done
```

Alternatively, you can do the whole thing in `awk`:

```
for sample in *.fastq.gz; do 
    printf '%s\t' "$sample"
    zcat "$sample" | awk '!(NR % 4){k++}END{print k}'
done
```

However, do note that there is nothing in the definition of the fastq format that says that files will only have 4 lines per sequence. If you know your data well you can use this approach, but if you need to deal with arbitrary fastq files, you cannot assume only 4 lines and would be better off using a dedicated tool.

You might find this Q&A interesting: [Fast way to count number of reads and number of bases in a fastq file?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/935/298).

And also the [FASTQ file](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2847217/#__sec7title) format specification which clarified that you cannot assume only 4 lines per entry. That said, in my significant experience in working on human NGS data these past ~7 years now in a clinical setting, every single file I've seen only ever had 4 lines per sample. But I don't work with long read data and the format itself allows for more so it's something to consider.